# "Appending" to an ArraySlice?

Tags: swift

Say ...

- you have about 20 Thing
- very often, you do a complex calculation running through a loop of say 1000 items.  The end result is a varying number around 20 each time
- you don't know how many there will be until you run through the whole loop
- you then want to quickly (and of course elegantly!) access the result set in many places
- for performance reasons you don't want to just make a new array each time. note that unfortunately there's a differing amount so you can't just reuse the same array trivially.

What about ...

```
var thingsBacking = [Thing](repeating: Thing(), count: 100) // hard limit!
var things: ArraySlice<Thing> = []

func fatCalculation() {

    var pin: Int = 0
    // happily, no need to clean-out thingsBacking
    for c in .. some huge loop {

        ... only some of the items (roughly 20 say) become the result
        x = .. one of the result items

        thingsBacking[pin] = Thing(... x, y, z )
        pin += 1
    }

    // and then, magic of slices ...
    things = thingsBacking[0..<pin]
```

(Then, you can do this anywhere... `for t in things { .. }`  )

What I am wondering, is there a way you can call to an `ArraySlice<Thing>` to do that in one step - to "append to" an ArraySlice and avoid having to bother setting the length at the end?

So, something like this ..

```
things = ... set it to zero length
things.quasiAppend(x)
things.quasiAppend(x2)
things.quasiAppend(x3)
```

With no further effort, `things` now has a length of three and indeed the three items are already in the backing array.

I'm particularly interested in performance here (unusually!)

Another approach,

```
var thingsBacking = [Thing?](repeating: Thing(), count: 100) // hard limit!
```

and just set the first one after your data to nil as an end-marker.  Again, you don't have to waste time zeroing. But the end marker is a nuisance.

Is there a more better way to solve this particular type of array-performance problem?

Comment: But you *can* call `.append()` on an array slice.

Comment: Another option might be to start with an empty *array* but call `reserveCapacity()` for better performance.

Comment: "But you can call .append() on an array slice"  **holy crap!**  :)  but what does it "do", does it put in in the "backing" - what is the backing? (Is it essentially the "most recent array you set the arrayslice to be a slice of" ... ?)   :O

Comment: One probably has to inspect the source code to find out :) – But why do you want a slice at all?

Comment: The slice's buffer will be made unique if you call `append(_:)` on it (it isn't uniquely referenced; both the array and slice have a view onto it), so you'll end up with two backing buffers.

Comment: How often are you re-populating the array? Something tells me that the single allocation of a new array (use `reserveCapacity(_:)` as Martin says) will be insignificant compared to the "complex calculation" you're doing (have you profiled?)

Comment: Also please please please please use the [swift] tag instead of [swift3]. It's a *general* language question not about a language change made in Swift 3, and is just as relevant in Swift 4 as it is in Swift 3. Besides, more people follow the [swift] tag than [swift3], so you're getting your question to a wider audience! (and also, you should generally include [swift] in addition to version-specific tags such as [swift3])

Comment: hey @Hamish !  funnily enough, being mindful of swift taggage, I actually thought in this case it is more very specifically about swift 3 (err -- 4)  But, sure, Swift works.

Comment: of course I will profile it, but, you surely see it's an obvious language question my man ...

Comment: "so you'll end up with two backing buffers" .. hmm; that's confusing; when does it "start a new one"?  Do you end up with another one every time you append, or each "run" after .. clearing the length, or ?

Comment: @MartinR "But why do you want a slice at all" Well, essentially because it's so easy/elegant to then `for t in things { .. }`  If it was embedded, I'd just take a chunk of memory, and simply keep track of how many there are - and that's it.  Or like I mention at "a simpler approach" you just do that (but man who wants to check for nil every time :) )  I mean the only deep answer is "it's more elegant, it's the whole point of slices" - sure.

Comment: `for t in things { .. }` works for arrays as well (an array is a collection is a sequence)

Comment: @Fattie It follows copy-on-write behaviour, and creates a new buffer if you attempt to perform a mutation on it when its own buffer is not uniquely referenced (i.e multiple collections have a view onto it). So repeatedly calling `append(_:)` won't create a new storage each time, as after the first append, you're already working off a uniquely referenced buffer (but if you then make it not uniquely referenced again, you'll get copying on mutation). Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43589637/2976878

Comment: I'm sure 'reserveCapacity' is perhaps the perfect solution here, I'll check it out!.  Is there a way to have array X, that has a reserve capacity of 100, and each time you zero it out it does use the same reserve?  Note @hamish and Martin, in the "complex" calculation, I *don't know how many until I have gone all the way through*, you know?

Comment: @Fattie: You mean `array.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)` ?

Comment: @Hamish, then, do you mean I'd just make a "totally new" ArraySlice *each time*  ie, precisely after the line `// and then, magic of slices ...`

Comment: brilliant @MartinR - and just append as I go through the loop??  (recall I tragically don't know the total count until having worked through the loop)

Comment: @Fattie I mean you'd have two buffers – one for the array (which wouldn't change if you're only ever mutating the slice via `.append`) and one for the slice (which would be nothing more than just an array in this case). The simple rule to remember is that both `Array` and `ArraySlice` have value semantics – so you should really think of them as two separate collections (it just happens that the slice can share storage with the array in most cases).

Comment: Right - I really think an ArraySlice is not a useful solution here, since it appears that if you just '.append' in to an array, where, you previously used `.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)` ......... that indeed performs the magic of changing the length in one go (since we don't know the length needed until we finish the large loop), and, using the same backing all the time.

Comment: @Fattie Yup, I'd say that's the best solution to your problem.

Comment: I put in an answer, @MartinR - feel free to delete, edit, usurp etc

Comment: There's a question that really needs a canonical answer, you men!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on MartinR's comments, it would seem that for the problem

- the data points are incoming and
- you don't know how many there will be until the last one (always less than a limit) and
- you're having to redo the whole thing at high Hz

It would seem to be best to just:

(1) set up the array

```
var ra = [Thing](repeating: Thing(), count: 100) // hard limit!
```

(2) at the start of each run,

```
 .removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
```

(3) just go ahead and `.append` each one.

(4) you don't have to especially mark the end or set a length once finished.

It seems it will indeed then use the same array backing. And it of course "increases the length" as it were each time you append - and you can iterate happily at any time.

Slices - get lost!

Comment: As said in the comments, you can also call `reserveCapacity(_:)` on an empty array to pre-allocate the buffer to (at least) a given length, then you can just append to it as normal (without the cost of reallocations until you reach the capacity). That saves you from having to pre-initialise it with "dummy data".

Comment: Cool @hamish.  It's annoying you can't seem to do that in the declaration.  if you try this .. `var xxx: [ColumnInfo] = { return [ColumnInfo].re ... }` it gives an interesting autocomplete!

Comment: Yeah, the stdlib is a bit inconsistent w.r.t `reserveCapacity`. For example, both `Dictionary` and `Set` have initialisers that take a capacity, e.g `var d = [String: Int](minimumCapacity: 20)`, but in Swift 3 they don't currently have `reserveCapacity(_:)` methods (but will do in Swift 4). Really I think that `Array` should also have an `init(minimumCapacity:)` – but you could always implement it in an extension :) `extension Array { init(minimumCapacity: Int) { self.init(); reserveCapacity(minimumCapacity) } }`

Comment: right.  if you try the autocomplete as shown, it gives a weird by-reference thing!

Comment: Yeah, it gives you the curried instance members – see https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/ (though the partial application is disallowed for `mutating` methods, such as `reserveCapacity(_:)`)